# Forced to use mutable to read Excel ThisWorkbook.Names?

Tags: excel, collections, f#, names

I am trying to get the data in an Excel named range for an F# based add-in. I want to be able to use named ranges anywhere in the workbook, not just a specific worksheet.

```
let xlRange (xl:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application, name:string) =
    let name_list = xl.ThisWorkbook.Names:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Names
    let mutable result=null
    for n in name_list do
        let nn = n :?> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Name
        if nn.Name = name then
            let range=nn.RefersToRange
            result <- range.Value2 :?> obj[,]
    result
```

The above code works, but I don't like it because I had to use a mutable and imperative style. The problem is the Excel.Names collection doesn't behave very well. For example

```
let name_seq = Seq.toList name_list
```

gives

> The type 'Names' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'

Is there a more F# idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: Try `Seq.toList (Seq.cast name_list)`, maybe even specify a type (i.e. `let name_seq : ... = ...`).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Seq.cast` to cast `name_list` to a typed sequence.

The advantage is obvious; you have better interoperability with F# and could use high-order functions in [Seq module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353635) instead of imperative `for` loop.

```
let xlRange (xl: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application, name: string) =
    xl.ThisWorkbook.Names
    |> Seq.cast<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Name> 
    |> Seq.tryPick (fun n -> if n.Name = name 
                             then Some (n.RefersToRange.Value2 :?> obj[,])
                             else None)
```

The return type now is `obj[,] option` which gives you type safety for free.

Comment: Thanks this what I tried at first but I get `the type 'Names' is not compatible with the type 'IEnumerable'`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use the Seq. things directly because of incompatible types.
I made this function which aims to convert the collection to an F# list which I could then process as above. It compiled fine but I didn't test because...

```
let xlNamesToList names =
    let rec xlNameList_r (names:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Names) idx =
        if idx>names.Count then // should this be >= ?
            []
        else
            names.Item(idx)::xlNameList_r names (idx+1)
    xlNameList_r names 0
```

...then I found a simpler way to do it directly:

```
let xlRange (xl:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application, name:string) =
    try
        let r=xl.ThisWorkbook.Names.Item(name :> obj).RefersToRange
        Some(r.Value2 :?> obj[,])
    with
        | _ -> None
```

Thanks for the help guys!